# in ifelse function is there a way to create something first then return the result if the statement is TRUE?

Tags: r

I am truly a beginner in r programming. And I am stuck with this problem. What I try to do is that if the ifelse true then create a vector including different value. Such as if my `q.matri= c(1,0,0)` then I would like to get a vector something like that `(0.2466072,0.7819847)`.But it gives me the only one value which is `0.2466072`. Is not it possible to do such things with ifelse function? 
Thanks in advance!

```
 a= function(q.matri){
      pc <- runif(1, IQ - VAR, IQ + VAR)
      p0 <- runif(1,0.20 - VAR , 0.20 + VAR)  
      p2 <-runif(1,0.25 - VAR , 0.25 + VAR)
      p3 <-runif(1,0.30 - VAR , 0.30 + VAR)
    ifelse (
      (sum(q.matri)==1),
          c(p0,pc),
      ifelse (
        (sum(q.matri)==2),
        c(p0, rep(p2, 2), pc),
      ifelse (
        (sum(q.matri)==3),
        c(p0, rep(p2, 3), rep(p3, 3), pc)
      )))}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I used the code you posted to formulated the program in R

```
a= function(q.matri){
pc = 1
p0 = 2
p2 =3
p3 =4
if(sum(q.matri)==1){
 return(c(p0,pc))
}else if(sum(q.matri)==2){
 return(c(p0, rep(p2, 2), pc))
}else if(sum(q.matri)==3){
 return(c(p0, rep(p2, 3), rep(p3, 3), pc))
}}
```

About the IQR and Var function you need to specify about what data you want to calculate it, this link [IQR](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/IQR.html) explain how to use the IQR function in R and this link [Var](http://www.r-tutor.com/elementary-statistics/numerical-measures/variance) explain how to use the VAR function.

Comment: Thank you so much. I got it. I think I forgot to present my var and IQ values since they were on the first lines of my code.  but this answer solved my problem